# Как сделать чтобы бот «ответил» на нажатие пользователя на определенный элемент в клавиатуре (telebot)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Нужно чтобы бот отвечал при нажатии на кнопку 'Give me a random number, please' определенное сообщение.
Трудность состоит в том, что я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы бот что-то ответил на нажатие кнопки
Код:

````
import random

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard1.row('Give me a random number, please')
number = random.random()

bot = telebot.TeleBot("APIKEY")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi, this is a bot which can send u a random number \nEnjoy!", reply_markup=keyboard1)
    if message.text.lower() == ("Give me a random number, please"):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, number)

bot.polling() ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше условие приводит входящий текст к нижнему регистру, но проверяется с разным:

```
message.text.lower() == ("Give me a random number, please"):
```

Надо

```
message.text.lower() == ("give me a random number, please"):
```